# Start Java jar with log4j on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: java, powershell, logging, log4j, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to start java jar with log4j config in specific location in Windows Server  2012 R2 PowerShell (or command line).

I tried the following command:

```
java -jar C:\myApp\myApp.jar -Duser.dir=C:\myApp -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\myApp\resources\log4j.xml
```

But the app fails to start with log4j error (after the WARN):

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (cz.mypackage.Myclass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

The same jar file with same log4j.xml, run by same command on Windows 2003 (with same version of Java) starts correctly.

I also tried several modifications of log4j file URI ("file://C:\myApp\resources\log4j.xml","file://C:/myApp/resources/log4j.xml", "file://C:\\myApp\\resources\\log4j.xml" or "file:C:\\myApp\\resources\\log4j.xml") as I found all over Internet.

Does anyone has any suggestions, how to start the jar?

Answer (score 1):

The magic is in using quotes and running from administrator PowerShell (I don't know why, but it works):

```
java -jar "C:\myApp\myApp.jar" -Duser.dir=C:\myApp -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\myApp\resources\log4j.xml
```